# How can I change the 'pivot-point' of this flip animation?

Tags: css, animation

I've been playing around with this CSS3 Animation, but I can't get it to pivot from a different location than the middle.

It is an animation that causes a flip-like effect from the middle where the top-half goes into the negative z-axis and the bottom-half goes into the positive z-axis.

I am trying to get the pivot-point to be the top so as the element that this animation is applied to is transformed, the entire element goes into the positive z-axis.

And then the flipOut animation would just be the reverse of that.

I'd appreciate any help in getting this animation to behave as I described.

Here is the code that runs the animation right now:

```
 .animated {
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    -o-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flipInX {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    40% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(-10deg);
    }

    70% {
       -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(10deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes flipInX {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    40% {
        -moz-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(-10deg);
    }

    70% {
        -moz-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(10deg);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes flipInX {
    0% {
        -o-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    40% {
        -o-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(-10deg);
    }

    70% {
        -o-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(10deg);
    }

    100% {
        -o-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes flipInX {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    40% {
        transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(-10deg);
    }

    70% {
        transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(10deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.flipInX {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
    -webkit-animation-name: flipInX;
    -moz-backface-visibility: visible !important;
    -moz-animation-name: flipInX;
    -o-backface-visibility: visible !important;
    -o-animation-name: flipInX;
    backface-visibility: visible !important;
    animation-name: flipInX;
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipOutX {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes flipOutX {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
         opacity: 1;
    }
100% {
         -moz-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
         opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes flipOutX {
    0% {
        -o-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
100% {
        -o-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes flipOutX {
     0% {
        transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
100% {
        transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.flipOutX {
    -webkit-animation-name: flipOutX;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
    -moz-animation-name: flipOutX;
    -moz-backface-visibility: visible !important;
    -o-animation-name: flipOutX;
    -o-backface-visibility: visible !important;
    animation-name: flipOutX;
    backface-visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the [transform origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform-origin):

```
transform-origin : center top;
```

Per MDN docs:

```
transform-origin: x-offset                                   /* One-value syntax */   E.g.  transform-origin: 2px 
transform-origin: offset-keyword                                                      E.g.  transform-origin: bottom

transform-origin: x-offset y-offset                          /* Two-value syntax */   E.g.  transform-origin: 3cm 2px
transform-origin: y-offset x-offset-keyword                                           E.g.  transform-origin: 2px left
transform-origin: x-offset-keyword y-offset                                           E.g.  transform-origin: left 2px
transform-origin: x-offset-keyword y-offset-keyword                                   E.g.  transform-origin: right top
transform-origin: y-offset-keyword x-offset-keyword                                   E.g.  transform-origin: top right

transform-origin: x-offset y-offset z-offset                 /* Three-value syntax */ E.g.  transform-origin: 2px 30% 10px
transform-origin: y-offset x-offset-keyword z-offset                                  E.g.  transform-origin: 2px left 10px
transform-origin: x-offset-keyword y-offset z-offset                                  E.g.  transform-origin: left 5px -3px
transform-origin: x-offset-keyword y-offset-keyword z-offset                          E.g.  transform-origin: right bottom 2cm
transform-origin: y-offset-keyword x-offset-keyword z-offset                          E.g.  transform-origin: bottom right 2cm
```