# webkit flip animation position not always on middle

Tags: css, animation, css-position, flip

i have this animation on my website fit-life.info

`div.anim {
    -webkit-animation: flipInX 1.2s 0s ease forwards;
    -moz-animation: flipInX 1.2s 0s ease forwards;
    -o-animation: flipInX 1.2s 0s ease forwards;
    animation: flipInX 1.2s 0s ease forwards;
    opacity: 0; }`

but some times some elements doesnt animate from the middle like this page post image http://fit-life.info/fitness/koiliako-lipos-kathimerina-lathoi-pou-prokaloun-tin-auksisi-tou-2/ 
i think my problem can be solved like the solution i have seen in this post [How can I change the 'pivot-point' of this flip animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354772/how-can-i-change-the-pivot-point-of-this-flip-animation) but i dont know where i have to put the

`transform-origin : center;`

maybe my page is loading too fast and the javascript is getting the wrong element position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animations afterall was triggered with javascript. a script animates every tag that has the class animate changing the opacity from 0 to 1

Answer (score 1):

You may need to include vendor(browser) prefixes, try adding:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
```